# Refresh View with new content not using any Adapter in multiple choice Test app

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-activity, multiple-choice

I am a newbee in Android app creating world.

I am creating an app where multiple choice questions are there. And, it could be 25, 50 or 100 depend on what user chooses. Now in an Activity, there would a question with 4 options along with next/prev button to navigate to the next or previous question. 
How can I achieve the next/previous button function which will display the next/previous question in the same activity just updating the content with new question or previously answered question?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way (although maybe not the best in other's opinions) is to define one Activity with a TextView for the question and a RadioGroup with RadioButtons for the answers. (And ofcourse the buttons.)

Then, whenever one of the buttons is pressed, dynamically change the contents of the TextView so that the right question appears and change the contents of the radiobuttons so that the possible answers appear. Store whichever RadioButton is chosen whenever the user presses one of the buttons.

You could store the questions and answers in a database. The `onClickListener()` assigned to the button should then get the next record in the database and use `yourTextView.setText(theQuestionFromTheDB)`. Same holds for the answers.
To store the chosen answer you can use

```
int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

and then write that value to the database.

Instead of a database, you could also use collectiosn like an arrays in your code, but I think this will be kind of painful to read all the questions to it initially. This is ofcourse, depending on where you get the questions from. If it is a raw .txt file or something that you dynamically want to read into your app, then an array or ArrayList is not all that bad.

For an example of how to add and use RadioButtons in your activity UI, [click here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/).

Comment: If you have a more specific question about my answer, please let me know. I see that you have only once accepted an answer and two times you did not. And in those cases you did not comment on why the answer would not be good enough. The least you can do when somebody takes the time to try to answer you question is accept/upvote their answer or give feedback on it, so they may improve it for you until you accept/upvote.

Comment: I apologize for the same. I was trying to understand your answer and implement the same. I just want to correct m understanding that as u said "yourTextView.setText(theQuestionFromTheDB)" that means it will upload the new content in the text view within the same activity and same goes for Radio Button (answer option) also. Am I right?

Comment: No problem. I at least hope it helps you :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. That is what I meant. You just reuse the `TextView` and the `RadioButton`s in the same `Activity` over and over by just overwriting their text.